# Finding whether the passed value is greater than zero or not using SQL functiom

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a user defined function which takes price as input parameter and returns if the input is greater than zero or not.
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
I have tried as follows.

```
create function fn_GreateCheck(@value int)
returns varchar(20)
as
begin    
select  case
when @value >0 then 'Greater'
when @value <0 then 'Lesser'
end

return @value     
end
```

Please help me on this

Thanks.

Comment: @krishna are you tried? can you share your code snippet.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: `when @value >0 then 'Greater'
when @value >0 then 'Lesser'` both cases are same. So the second case did not make any sense.

Comment: @krishna Why did you tag `oracle10g` when your database is `sqlserver`? Please use appropriate tags for your question.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience second case is @Value<0

Comment: Why do you want a function for this? It would seem to just be hiding a very straightforward `>` comparison.

Comment: @krishna if your where condition is like this `where P_Price=@value`, than all your results are same. right?

Comment: ok fine i do not have any table just i will pass the value then output should come as Greater or lesser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
create function dbo.fn_GreateCheck(@value int)
returns varchar(20)
as
begin    
    declare @ret VARCHAR(20) = (case
        when @value >0 then 'Greater'
        when @value <0 then 'Lesser'
        else 'Zero'
    end)

    return @ret
end
GO

select dbo.fn_GreateCheck (1000) --> Greater
select dbo.fn_GreateCheck (-10)  --> Lesser
select dbo.fn_GreateCheck (0)    --> Zero
select dbo.fn_GreateCheck (NULL) --> Zero
GO
```

A user defined function cannot return data to the client, so you have to catch the result in a variable and return the value. To return a result set, you have to define [Table-value user defined function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx).